# Extracting content .img file

Tags: c#, wpf, binaryfiles, memorystream

I am working on a project where we have to extract information from `.img` file. What is known, is that `.img` file contains image with 512x512 pixels, and size of each pixel is 2 bits of type `short`. 
We have to extract that image form the file. The question is, how to read that file with `C#`? My current line for binary reading is:

`byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\temp\Jonatan\test23.img");`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You did it, you just read it. Now what do you want to do with that information? Draw it onto an image and display or save that in another format? Then you'll have to create a Bitmap and assign pixel colors.

Comment: Yes, I want to display it. How can I assign pixel colors?

Comment: Some image files have a [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) that indicates the file format. What are the first few bytes of the file?

Comment: It is sequence of 0 and 248

Comment: See if that matches one of the formats [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). If not, it's hard to tell what it actually is, and how the pixels are encoded. Who created that file? Probably ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the actual format of your pixel data, creating a bitmap from the byte array might be as simple as this:

```
var width = 512;
var height = 512;
var stride = width * 2;

var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
    width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null, bytes, stride);
```

You might now have an Image element in XAML

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

and set its Source property to the BitmapSource:

```
image.Source = bitmap;
```